# Unit test "fail" method unable to find the reference to the test class

Tags: python, xcode, python-unittest

I am using python unittest to test a web app using selenium. In my teardownClass, I am calling cls.fail but it returns "AttributeError" saying that "failureException" not found in the "string".

Here is what my teardownClass method looks like:

```py
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        browser_logs = cls.driver.get_log("browser")
        errors = [log_entry['message'] for log_entry in browser_logs if logentry['level'] == 'SEVERE']
        if errors:
            cls.fail(errors)
```

this returns the following attributeError:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: tearDownClass (__main__.unitTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shahrukh/Desktop/apollotest/test_users.py", line 239, in tearDownClass
    cls.fail("error")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 670, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'failureException'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

"fail" method from /usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py file:

```py
    def fail(self, msg=None):
        """Fail immediately, with the given message."""
        raise self.failureException(msg)
```

This method is part of "Testcase" class

The problem is that fail method above does not find the reference to self. "errors" in my code is a string object. So when I call `cls.fail(errors)` it considers self=errors and msg remains None.

I don't get this problem if I change my code statement to `cls.fail(cls, errors)`.

I want to understand why am I experiencing this behavior? Am I missing anything because according to my understanding `cls.fail` should mean that `self` in fail method is equal to `cls`.

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Try changing "cls" to "self" in the class

Comment: i have changed this as well but same result.

Comment: its working fine when i write these line in the function, not in tear down.

Comment: Does anything change when writing in function?

Comment: `fail` and `failureException` are instance methods, so you need a `TestCase` instance to call them. E.g. `tc = TestCase(); tc.fail('woohoo')` will work, but not `TestCase.fail('woohoo')`. The latter is what you're effectively executing in `tearDownClass`. Move the teardown logic to `tearDown` method.